# django Static files are served, but not admin css

Tags: django, static-files

I have my website in production mode and the static files are served properly in it, with debug=False. But the admin page css are not loader. I have my static URL as `/assets/`, with static root as:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
```

Now, I have admin folder inside the static folder. But

```
mysite.com/assets/admin/css/base.css
```

I also tried adding `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX='/assets/admin/` to my settings.py, which did not help
gives a 404 Error.